# How to instruct StandardAnalyzer in Lucene to not to remove stop words?

Tags: lucene

Simple question : How to make Lucene's `StandardAnalyzer` not to remove stop words when analyzing my sentence ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is version-dependent. For [Lucene 3.0.3 (current)](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html), you need to construct the StandardAnalyzer with an empty set of stop words, using something like this:

```
Analyzer ana = new StandardAnalyzer(LUCENE_30, Collections.emptySet());
```

Comment: Thought so... Was waiting if someone would say "there is something in API to do so" :) I guess I'll go with your answer then :)

Answer (score 7):

Update:
the answer is version-dependent. For Lucene 4.0, use:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40, CharArraySet.EMPTY_SET);
```

Note that the `StandardAnalyzer` is not in the lucene-core jar, but in `lucene-analyzers-common-4.0.0.jar`

Answer (score 2):

For Lucene 6.0.0, use

```
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = StandardAnalyzer(CharArraySet.EMPTY_SET);
```