# How to return a row where all values in an array exists

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database where values are stored like this:

```
Id                 Description
 1                  one,two,three,four,five
 2                  four,three,two
 3                  five,one
```

and also I have dynamic array coming from user like this:

```
1) $arr = array("five","one");
```

so I have to select description with id=1 and id=3 because their descriptions contains these words.

Another example

```
2) $arr = array("two","three");
```

so I have to select description with id=1 and id=2 because their descriptions contains these words.

so how to execute that query?
Anybody can help?

Comment: Looks like you database needs normalizing

Comment: ... or don't bother with the database!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could try fulltext-search:

like

```
string str = string.Join(" +", $arr);
str = str.Replace("'","''");

string strSQL = @"SELECT * FROM 
your_table WHERE 
MATCH ( Description) 
AGAINST ('" + str + "' IN BOOLEAN MODE);"
```

Which results in:

```
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 
                     your_table WHERE 
                     MATCH ( Description) 
                     AGAINST ('+one +five' IN BOOLEAN MODE);");
```

Make sure you remove all stopwords from the mysql config file.

As for the plus sign:

**1st sql example**

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
          WHERE match(Description) against('+one +five' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 10";
```

result: contains the words 'one' and 'five'

**2nd sql example**

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
           WHERE match(Description) against('+one five' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 10";
```

result: contains the words 'one', but rank rows higher if they also contain 'five'

**3rd sql example**

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
           WHERE match(Description) against('one five' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 10";
```

result: contains the words 'one' or 'five'

Comment: @DarkBee: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952900/mysql-search-query-keep-not-working/24953897#24953897

Comment: @Quandary: I also want to say array can be of unlimited no. of elements. I am showing just two elements only for example purpose

Comment: @AnuragJain If this answere helped you or did what you wanted / expected, please mark it as such.

Comment: @Michal-sk웃 No thats not the answer I am looking for because my table does not support full text search

Comment: @Anurag Jain: Full-text search is supported since MySQL V 3.23.23. You need to use the MyISAM engine for the table and add the fulltext-index: ALTER TABLE your_table  ADD FULLTEXT( Description );

Comment: Full-text search is supported in both MyISAM and InnoDB since MySQL v5.6.

Answer (score 1):

Barring full-text search or properly normalizing your data (i.e. [don't use comma delimited data if you must search through it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)), then you can use `FIND_IN_SET()` to search comma delimited strings.

However, since the first argument of `FIND_IN_SET()` doesn't accept a comma separated list, you must first separate the search terms (see PHP's [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)).

With some iteration, you can create a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('five', description)
  AND FIND_IN_SET('one', description)
```

Sometimes, when you're dynamically creating such queries, it's easier to create a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE 1 = 1
/* Start dynamic portion */
  AND FIND_IN_SET('five', description)
  AND FIND_IN_SET('one', description)
```

Or, actually, if you're properly using PDO bound parameters:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE 1 = 1
/* Start dynamic portion */
  AND FIND_IN_SET(?, description)
  AND FIND_IN_SET(?, description)
```

Use PHP's `bindParam()` to bind each parameter.

Comment: If you use WHERE 1=1 instead of WHERE 1, then it will be compatible with standard-sql.

Answer (score 1):

I have done it using "like" parameter. See the below code

```
$count = 1;


 foreach($arr as $a){
            if($count == 1){
               $str ="`Description` LIKE '%$a%'";
            }
             else{
               $str.= "AND `Description` LIKE '%$a%'"; 
            }
            $count++;
        }
$query = Select `id` From `my_table` Where $str;
```

This is not the best way.But this is giving me the result I am wanting

Comment: If you do WHERE (1=1) + ==IN FOR LOOP === AND `Description` LIKE '%$a%'  === END FOR LOOP === Then you can skip the count part, and it works great if you have a null array, and you save 7 lines of code.

Comment: This method could work if you only have 'one' through 'thirteen', but if you go further, 'four' also appears in 'fourteen'. That's why `FIND_IN_SET()` is typically used for this kind of search, over wildcard string search. If you're to the point where you're searching for ',four,', then it's really getting complex.